# how to choose a suitble struct elemnt for small shapes

Tags: matlab, image-morphology

i am trying to erode a small shape, since it's a region on an MR images i can't find the suitble struct element disk doesn't work since the object is very small square doesn't give a good result,
the image :

[image]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's really difficult when object are really small. At this scale, you don't have many possibilities:

- square 3x3 (8-neighborhood, the biggest)
- disk 3x3 which is then just a simple cross (4-neighborhood)
- segments 3x3 with for possible orientations, but then you impose an orientation and you will get artifacts.

There is a last possibility that is more complicated to develop: an hexagon. You have to use tow different masks for the implementations, according to the row/line you process. It will give you a result between the cross and the square.

Btw, why do you want to achieve, maybe there an other solution than the erosion.

Comment: i need to erode the object since i want seeds that takes the object contour , one told me to use ray tracing algorithm but i don't realy have a good idea how can i use it, anyway thanks for the response

Comment: In that case, you don't really have much of a choice. You have to use one of the three: square, cross or hexagon. As I said, if square is to aggressive and cross is not enough, then a hexagon might be a good compromise.

Comment: For ray tracing, it's for 3D rendering, I don't see what it has to do with your work.